# Given a Turing Machine $M$ and a word $w$, can we tell if the Turing Machine will move its head at every step?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, decidability

The exercise I'm trying to solve is: Is the language $L = \{<M>,w\ |\ M \text{ moves its head on input } $w$ \text{ at every step}\}$ decidable or undecidable.
We work with a version of the TM that doesn't just move its head to the left or right but can also stay in place. My feeling is that the problem is undecidable and I'm trying to find a way to reduce the special Halting problem to this problem, but until now without any luck. Any tips would be very appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure this works, so I'm going to leave it as a comment rather than an answer.

To determine whether M halts on input x with an oracle for L, consider a program P that simulates running M on x. Whenever M would take another step in its computation, our program P advances the head of the machine along the tape. If M halts, pause P for one step, then halt.

Comment: The idea is that our program just moves its head along the tape in time with the action of M taking steps. If M halts on x, then P advances to the right until M does, then waits for a step, then halts. Hence P is not in L. If M does not halt on x, then it runs forever, so then P runs forever and always moves down the tape, consequently P is in L.

I'm a little concerned that P is not actually a program for the same kind of Turing machine that M is. My hope is some clever compiling will save you.

Comment: Based on the idea in the comments by @James, I suggest the following reduction of the halting problem to your set $L$. Given a Turing machine $M$, modify it so that, whenever $M$ would leave its head in the same place at some step, the modified machine $M'$ takes two steps, moving its head one space to the right and then back to the left.  Also, whenever $M$ enteers a halting state, $M'$ should perform one more step but not move its head. Then $M$ halts on input $w$ iff $(\langle M'\rangle,w)\notin L$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you for your answer! I have one more question though, how would I simulate one extra step in a TM without it moving its head? Because if every symbol on the tape for every state already has a transition, how can i simulate one extra step when the TM does not move its head?

Comment: Just change the instructions of $M$ by giving each halting state a transition which, regardless of the symbol it's reading on the tape, doesn't move, doesn't write, but transitions to a new halting state.